# pandas read_csv() input local datetime strings, tz_convert to UTC

Tags: python, timezone, pandas

I am using pandas-0.8rc2 to read an input CSV with two columns of localized
datetime strings lacking UTC offset information, and need the dataframe series
properly converted to UTC.

I've been trying workarounds to mitigate the fact that neither timestamp columns
represent the index, they are data. tz_localize and tz_convert apparently work
on the index of a series/dataframe only, not a column. I would very much like to
learn a better approach to do that, rather than the following code:

```
# test.py
import pandas

# input.csv:
# starting,ending,measure
# 2012-06-21 00:00,2012-06-23 07:00,77
# 2012-06-23 07:00,2012-06-23 16:30,65
# 2012-06-23 16:30,2012-06-25 08:00,77
# 2012-06-25 08:00,2012-06-26 12:00,0
# 2012-06-26 12:00,2012-06-27 08:00,77

df = pandas.read_csv('input.csv', parse_dates=[0,1])
print df

ser_starting = df.starting
ser_starting.index = ser_starting.values
ser_starting = ser_starting.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
ser_starting = ser_starting.tz_convert('UTC')

ser_ending = df.ending
ser_ending.index = ser_ending.values
ser_ending = ser_ending.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
ser_ending = ser_ending.tz_convert('UTC')

df.starting = ser_starting.index
print df
df.ending = ser_ending.index
print df
```

Second, the code is encountering some odd behavior. It changes the timestamp
data of the second assignment back to the data frame, whether the order is
df.starting or df.ending:

```
$ python test.py 
              starting               ending  measure
0  2012-06-21 00:00:00  2012-06-23 07:00:00       77
1  2012-06-23 07:00:00  2012-06-23 16:30:00       65
2  2012-06-23 16:30:00  2012-06-25 08:00:00       77
3  2012-06-25 08:00:00  2012-06-26 12:00:00        0
4  2012-06-26 12:00:00  2012-06-27 08:00:00       77
             starting               ending  measure
0 2012-06-21 04:00:00  2012-06-23 07:00:00       77
1 2012-06-23 11:00:00  2012-06-23 16:30:00       65
2 2012-06-23 20:30:00  2012-06-25 08:00:00       77
3 2012-06-25 12:00:00  2012-06-26 12:00:00        0
4 2012-06-26 16:00:00  2012-06-27 08:00:00       77
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    print df
  File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 572, in __repr__
    if self._need_info_repr_():
  File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 560, in _need_info_repr_
    self.to_string(buf=buf)
  File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1207, in to_string
    formatter.to_string(force_unicode=force_unicode)
  File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 200, in to_string
    fmt_values = self._format_col(i)
  File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 242, in _format_col
    space=self.col_space)
  File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 462, in format_array
    return fmt_obj.get_result()
  File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 589, in get_result
    fmt_values = [formatter(x) for x in self.values]
  File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 597, in _format_datetime64
    base = stamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ValueError: year=1768 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900
```

The print statements are just to demonstrate the problem. The incorrect values
will carry through without exception if I avoid repr and other methods that call
strftime.

The strange part is that if I keep calling the df.{starting,ending} assignments
at the repl, I usually end up with a correct dataframe, with timestamps:

```
In [151]: df
Out[151]: 
             starting              ending  measure
0 2012-06-21 04:00:00 2012-06-23 11:00:00  77
1 2012-06-23 11:00:00 2012-06-23 20:30:00  65
2 2012-06-23 20:30:00 2012-06-25 12:00:00  77
3 2012-06-25 12:00:00 2012-06-26 16:00:00   0
4 2012-06-26 16:00:00 2012-06-27 12:00:00  77
```

This is not repeatable, AFAICT, I can't describe the exact sequence of calls
that gets past the ValueError above, but it does

I would appreciate any thoughts about whether if I'm up against a bug,
or if this is unsupported API usage.

And as mentioned above, I'd rather just learn a better usage of the pandas API
to avoid doing it this way.

Answer (score 5):

it appears there may be a bug lurking here, so I've created an issue here, will take a look soon and let you know:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1518

EDIT: the bug you encountered has been fixed. I'm going to fix the pre-1900 display issue right now, too.